# Reusable UIView Animation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

Consider this basic view animation.  It will scale a view down to nothing over the course of 1 second:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     vw.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.0);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         vw.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                     }
                 }
];
```

What I'd like to do is use this same animation on many different views at different times throughout my app.  To do this, I can easily put it in a method, pass in the view I want to zoom.  No problem.

The challenge is that I may need to do different things at the completion of the animation depending on the situation.  For example, I may want to remove the view from the SuperView in one case, and I may want to move the view to a new location (for zooming in later) in another case.

In a nutshell:  How can I notify the caller of my method when the animation completes?

```
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        vw.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        // Do something unique here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just pass in the completion block itself as well:

```
- (void)animateView:(UIView *)v completion:(void ^(BOOL))ch
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         v.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.0);
                     }
                     completion:ch
    ];
}
```

Then call it like

```
[self animateView:someView completion:^(BOOL flag) {
    // do stuff here
}];
```

Comment: I am beginning to fall in love with Blocks.  Nice, elegant solution -- thanks!

Comment: @Axeva No problem. I love blocks, me too. Too bad my toolchain doesn't support them (and too bad they're not standard). The only useful extension to C/Objective-C Apple made.